# ASP.Net Core : Generic Controller & Model Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very noob in C# and .NET ecosystem, sorry if question stupid.

What I am trying to do is having a `EventController` and `ArticleController` which both inherits from `PageController`, same applies for models : Event and Article inherits from Page, sharing the same ID sequence.

I'd like to provide these URLs (among other, but to simplify) :

- /Pages (which shows both Articles and Pages together)
- /Articles (which shows only Articles)
- /Events (which shows only Events)

Here's a simplified concept of the code I'm trying to accomplish :

```
using System;
using CoolSite.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SharpBusiness.Data;

namespace CoolSite.Models
{
    public abstract class Page
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
        string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class Article : Page
    {
    }

    public class Event : Page
    {
        DateTime When { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CoolSite.Controllers
{
    public class PageController<T> : Controller where T : Page
    {
        private readonly GeneralContext _db;
        protected GeneralContext Db { get => _db; }

        protected virtual DbSet<T> AllEntities { get => Db.Pages; }

        public PageController(GeneralContext context) => _db = context;

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult List() => View(AllEntities);
    }

    public class ArticleController : PageController<Article>
    {
        public ArticleController(GeneralContext context) : base(context) { }
        protected override DbSet<Article> AllEntities { get => Db.Articles; }
    }
    public class EventController : PageController<Event>
    {
        public EventController(GeneralContext context) : base(context) { }
        protected override DbSet<Event> AllEntities { get => Db.Events; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, at that line :

```
protected virtual DbSet<T> AllEntities { get => Db.Pages; }
```

I am getting that error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet' (CS0029)

Is that possible to make this works ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DbContext` has a generic method to get a repoitory for any type - `Db.GetRepository<T>()` or something like that

Comment: Have a `SharedController` like your current `PageController` (but with an abstract `AllEntities`). Then have `PageController` and the other two controllers inherit from `SharedController` (not from `PageController`).

Comment: @mjwills This seems good, but the problem is that I made a complex class structure, it would not be very elegant.

Comment: Step 1 - make it work. Step 2 - make it elegant.

Comment: You just need to use the "context", leave the dbset in the context class and it should work correctly. [take a look pls](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `Set<T>`. Although, you shouldn't persist this in an ivar, mostly because there's no point. When you want to query just use `_db.Set<T>()`. When adding/removing entities, you can just use `_db.Add(entity)`, `_db.Remove(entity)`, etc. EF Core will do the operation on the appropriate `DbSet` for that entity type.

Comment: Damnnnnnnn that's what i'm talking about ! It is even more elegant than expected !! Thank you very much my friend !